# How to tell bitcoind to use more memory and CPU

Tags: bitcoind, cpu, raspberry-pi, bitcoin.conf, memory

I just updated my node to 0.12 and its going through its long verification process but I noticed that its not using very much memory/cpu

```
pi         602 10.5 19.4 352220 184312 ?       Ssl  21:57   1:28 /usr/local/bin/bitcoind -datadir=/home/pi/bitcoinData/.bitcoin -daemon
```

How can I configure it to optimise all available memory and cpu? I recall a option to bump up the cache from a default of 50 or 100mb but cannot find the option.

I have a 1GB PI 2. Any recommendations on maximum memory to use? I was thinking 900mb if possible.

Thank you for your tips, and any optimizations to make this run best would be great!

Answer (score 8):

It will by default use all CPU cores available.

However, if the database cache is too small, your node will spend its time fetching and writing database entries from/to disk, rather than verification

You can set the size of the database cache using a bitcoin.conf setting `dbcache=N`, where N is the number of megabytes of RAM.

Comment: Thank you very much Pieter! I did not expect you to answer the question, thanks for taking the time out of your day to solve a minor issue!

When upgrading to 12.0 from 11.99, how long do you think the verification process should take for all blocks on a RPi2?

error: couldn't connect to server

Im getting that after running bitcoin-cli getinfo and its said that for approx 5 hours now.

Comment: @Murch may be able to answer how long, I think it took him several weeks. Not sure what dbcache setting he used. Note that a Pi is always going to be somewhat memory deprived. The UTXO set is 1.5 GB on disk and a multiple of that in memory, so it will be (re)loading parts of that constantly as well.

Comment: @xenostar: I ran a full synchronization on a Raspberry Pi 2 with 12rc01, IIRC it took more than four weeks.